# Upgrading from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, upgrade, coldfusion-9, cfml, coldfusion-2016

We are upgrading from ColdFusion 9 (Windows Server 2008) to ColdFusion 2016 (Windows Server 2016). We use siteminder webagent for SSO authentication and configure CF in IIS 10.

Will there be any tag deprecation and will it require code changes?

Comment: We cannot answer this question as it is too vague. We don't know what tags or functions your code is using. You will need to build a development server and test it out to see what breaks.  Then come back and ask specific questions if need be and provide code that shows the problem. You can read up on the [deprecated features of ColdFusion here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/deprecated-features.html). Note that some (maybe most) are deprecated in ColdFusion 2018, not 2016. The page details when the feature was deprecated.

Comment: You can expect things to break whenever you upgrade.  Sometimes you discover them in advance, sometimes after the fact.  When my former employer made a similar upgrade, we used both methods to discover problems.  The one I remember most had to do with applet grids that had to be changed to html grids.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan Bracuk and Miguel-F.

Comment: I would also suggest that you build in some expectations for code refactoring above just what breaks. There is a pretty large difference in the way things should be done between CF9 and CF2016, _especially_ in the security area.

Comment: And one of your biggest changes will be moving from JRun to Tomcat. That might cause you some unexpected issues. Also, you can never go wrong reading some of Charlie Arehart's great work. https://www.carehart.org/presentations/whats_new_in_cf10_11_2016.pdf That's a pretty decent overview, but he has a lot of other info on the changes in each version.

Comment: And also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUoPx3jrh6M&feature=youtu.be&list=PLz6r7YssJoKSlZk78GeJdIlLzXcSg4w1d

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the ColdFusion admin -> Debugging & Logging is the Code Analyzer. It will scan your site for compatibility concerns it finds. It may miss some things but it will give you a starting point.

The screenshot below is for ColdFusion 2018. 2016 has similar functionality

[image]

Comment: I was going to mention using the Code Analyzer, but James beat me to it. It will catch most issues.